# Pause event till next day and continue with the rest of the python code

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm trying to automate some processes on my laptop...like checking mail, messaging, sending birthday wishes etc

The code is pretty simple for all of them but what i want now is that, for instance, after the function for checking email has being executed, the function should deactivate till the next day...
And the same should happen to the other functions.
All those functions are in the same file and executed in order

So it's more like :
wish_birthday_func()
wish_birthday_func.pause_next_day#even if i #run the file again during the #same day
check_mail_func() #.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wouldn't like a permanently running task because you could reboout your latop right ?

So you should look for some sheduler of your os (Windows at, Linux cron etc.)

Comment: And please how will i do that? Just want a lead so i follow. I currently do not know how to interact with the operating system using python code

Comment: basically you don't do it from python. you do it from your os. What's your operation system ?

Comment: Windows 10.....

Comment: Than you could look for schtasks.exe

Comment: Ok thanks...will give you feedback